# Fastlane doesn't work after updating to macOS Catalina [using Fishshell]

Tags: ruby, rubygems, fastlane, macos-catalina, fish

"The file '/usr/local/bin/fastlane' specified the interpreter '/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/ruby', which is not an executable command."

Comment: Note that command completion gets very slow with fish 3.0.* on Catalina. See https://sourceforge.net/p/fish/mailman/message/36907327/ for the workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix it by:

1.) `sudo gem install fastlane -NV`

*After this, try running your fastlane commands. In my case they didn't work but the output did suggest to run the next commands:*

2.) `sudo gem install bundler:2.0.2`

3.) `bundle update --bundler`

And now I'm running it using:

**bundle exec fastlane your_lane**
(instead of *fastlane your_lane*)

Comment: I get an error: **can't find executable fastlane for gem fastlane.**

Comment: Hard to say without additional info about the setup/config.
Maybe worth checking the location path is correct.